# C# / DateTime / как привести к часам

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

День добрый! На странице приложения показаны ивенты доступные для регистрации. Данный метод возвращает все активные ивенты. но проблема в том, что, к примеру: есть ивент сегодня в 11 утра. после 11 утра он ,по логике, НЕ должен показываться, но он висит как активный. И скрывается он только после полуночи. То есть он становится неактивным, когда меняется дата(т.е. конец периода не учитывает время)...Как лучше изменить DateTime чтоб ивент становился неактивным после заданного часа, а не на следующий день?

```
public IPagedList<Domain.Event> SearchEventsPublic(long[] eventCategoryTypeIds = null,
                                          long[] locationIds = null,
                                          DateTime? startDate = null,
                                          DateTime? endDate = null,
                                          int pageIndex = 0,
                                          int pageSize = int.MaxValue)
    {
        var query = _eventRepository.Table;
        // get event by filter
        if (eventCategoryTypeIds != null && eventCategoryTypeIds.Length > 0)
            query = query.Where(c => eventCategoryTypeIds.Contains(c.EventCategoryId));

        if (locationIds != null && locationIds.Length > 0)
            query = query.Where(c => locationIds.Contains(c.LocationId));

        var minDate = DateTime.Now;
        if (startDate.HasValue && startDate.Value > minDate)
        {
            minDate = startDate.Value.Date;
        }
        query = query.Where(c => c.StartDateTime >= minDate ||
                                (c.PrePurchase && (c.ParentId == null || c.ParentId == 0)));

        if (endDate.HasValue)
        {
            var maxDate = endDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
            query = query.Where(c => c.StartDateTime <= maxDate ||
                                (c.PrePurchase && (c.ParentId == null || c.ParentId == 0)));
        }

        query = query.OrderBy(c => c.PrePurchase ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(c => c.StartDateTime);
        return new PagedList<Domain.Event>(query.AsQueryable(), pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
```

Comment: Упростите код, потому что сейчас не ясно, проблема именно в сравнении дат или в том, что условие после ИЛИ оказывается истинным. Может там надо заменить на И? /// Приведите минимальный пример, можно с захардкоженой стартовой датой, без кучи лишних для нас ветвлений и приведите пример набора данных в БД, что хотите получить и что в итоге получаете

Comment: @АндрейNOP у меня есть для вас предложение по NOP Commerce. детали по адресу slvmlnkv@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Я использую `startDate.Value.Date` и это возвращает именно дату как часть  `DateTime`. Так что удалил `.Date` как привязку только к числу и сейчас все работает верно.

```
public IPagedList<Domain.Event> SearchEventsPublic(long[] eventCategoryTypeIds = null,
                                  long[] locationIds = null,
                                  DateTime? startDate = null,
                                  DateTime? endDate = null,
                                  int pageIndex = 0,
                                  int pageSize = int.MaxValue)
{
    var query = _eventRepository.Table;
    // get event by filter
    if (eventCategoryTypeIds != null && eventCategoryTypeIds.Length > 0)
        query = query.Where(c => eventCategoryTypeIds.Contains(c.EventCategoryId));

    if (locationIds != null && locationIds.Length > 0)
        query = query.Where(c => locationIds.Contains(c.LocationId));

    var minDate = DateTime.Now;
    if (startDate.HasValue && startDate.Value > minDate)
    {
        minDate = startDate.Value;
    }
    query = query.Where(c => c.StartDateTime >= minDate ||
                        (c.PrePurchase && (c.ParentId == null || c.ParentId == 0)));

    if (endDate.HasValue)
    {
        var maxDate = endDate.Value.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
        query = query.Where(c => c.StartDateTime <= maxDate ||
                        (c.PrePurchase && (c.ParentId == null || c.ParentId == 0)));
    }

    query = query.OrderBy(c => c.PrePurchase ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(c => c.StartDateTime);
return new PagedList<Domain.Event>(query.AsQueryable(), pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```